# linking Boost library to Xcode project

Tags: c++, xcode, boost

I'm trying to create a project that uses the Boost library. I'm on OS X 10.9.5 (I should update that) and using Xcode 6.2. I installed boost with homebrew `brew install boost` and it's located in `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.59.0`. I added the path the the `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.59.0/include` to the header search path in Xcode and it seems to recognize it because the autocomplete hinting works.

In the [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) it mentions that some of the Boost libraries must be built before they can be used. I assume homebrew took care of that because I have a bunch of `.a` and `.dylib` files in `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.59.0/lib`

I'm still new to C++ and the Xcode build process but it seems I still need to link the compiled libraries to my project. I tried adding the path `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.59.0/lib` to my project's library search paths but I'm not sure if that is correct.

Here is the error I get when I try to build my project.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::filesystem::detail::create_directory(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)", referenced from:
      boost::filesystem::create_directory(boost::filesystem::path const&) in main.o
  "boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)", referenced from:
      boost::filesystem::exists(boost::filesystem::path const&) in main.o
  "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init2 in main.o
  "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in main.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init1 in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is there something else I need to configure to get this to work?

Comment: @Eelke Great! Thanks I added those to the `Other Linker Flags` section of my project's build settings and it worked! If you make it an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the path is correct but you also need to specify the libraries you need. On the commandline you would use -l for that in Xcode you can add them to `Other Linker Flags`.

The libraries you need are `boost_filesystem` and `boost_system`.

Comment: Can you give the exact syntax? I'm trying to use boost and putting `-l boost_bind` in the Other Linker Flags section still gives "boost//bind.hpp file not found" errors in Xcode (both `#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>` and `#include <boost/bind.hpp>` fail)

Comment: You are missing the include path for boost. Can’t give details, posting from phone.

Comment: I most definitely am not. I installed boost with `brew` which compiles it to `/usr/local/Cellar/boost`, I've added the `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.65.1/include/` to my Header path, and `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.65.1/lib/` to the library search path, but when I look at the actual compile instruction (using Xcode's report navigator) there is *no* reference to those. So I added them exactly as Xcode says they should be, and then they're getting completely ignored.